# Managing Gherkin lines

Tags: javascript, gherkin

I have several bunches of test scenarios written in Gherkin and implemented in Javascript. There are several people who write scenarios in Gherkin (and don't implement lines in js code), so it is a common situation when different people use different words for the same step. 
F.i. step is: click on the "OK" button
*1st person writes*: User clicks OK
*2nd person writes*: User has clicked on ok button
*3rd person writes*: Click ok
etc
After that those who write code for these lines should:

- either implement all variants
- re-write all the similar lines so that they are the same

Both variants seem to be very inconvenient and time-consuming. So an idea to have some "Gherkin lines' database" appeared. 
Here comes the main question: Is there any tool to manage all Gherkin lines written/implemented for the project, where people could search for some suitable lines?

Comment: this is a big issue in my company. It's not something that kills tests but it's annoying to choose which. There isn't any management software I know of which "sorts" step definitions...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio creates the library for you.

We have our specflow in dutch, but you can see from the screenshot how Visual Studio offers implemented specflow steps only. You can then choose from the list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, still I'm looking for a separate tool for lines. I use Webstorm by JetBrains and it also has such feature, but it is not free and unfortunately we cannot afford purchasing the whole IDE just for this Gherkin feature...

Comment: Visual Studio community edition is free to use ;-) But I understand the problem. Hope someone else can help you with it then!